# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in a simple HelloWorld

Tags: java

I get the message after I try to start "java -cp . "HelloWorld"

Fehler: Hauptklasse .\HelloWorld konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /\HelloWorld

It's only a simple programm to check out, if the IDE is runnng correctly.

Comment: "to check out if the IDE is running", I have no idea how this is in any way related to an IDE

Comment: commandline `java HelloWorld` would have to be run from the same folder `HomeWorld` is located in

Comment: Which IDE?  You never say.  Where is the HelloWorld.class file?  Is it in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: Exactly what command line are you running? I get this error if I run `java -cp . .\HelloWorld`: note the dot and backslash before `HelloWorld`.

Answer (score 1):

check if java installed `java -version`
compile `javac HelloWorld.java`
run `java Helloworld`

Answer (score 0):

I used the Powershell to run the command. Inside of the cmd-Window it runs correctly. Thank you for the extensive help